# Are there any open task sets available to assess workload using secondary task measures?

Tags: methodology, experimental-psychology, software, human-factors

Performance on secondary tasks next to a primary task is sometimes used to assess mental workload (Ogden, Levine and Eisner, 1979). For example, the Stroop test as a secondary task has been evaluated by Gwizdka (2010).

However, a lot of effort goes into setting up these tasks, so I was wondering whether there are any open, ready-made task sets available which would be suitable for this purpose.

Some desirable characteristics I am looking for:

- One task shouldn't be considerably harder than another.
- Performing one task shouldn't take considerably longer than another.
- Overall, one task shouldn't take too long, so the amount of tasks done can also be used as a measurement of mental workload.

<sub>Ogden, G. D., Levine, J. M., & Eisner, E. J. (1979). [Measurement of workload by secondary tasks.](http://hfs.sagepub.com/content/21/5/529.short) Human Factors: The Journal of the Human Factors and Ergonomics Society, 21(5), 529-548.

Gwizdka, J. (2010, August). [Using stroop task to assess cognitive load](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1962300.1962345). In Proceedings of the 28th Annual European Conference on Cognitive Ergonomics (pp. 219-222). ACM.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned the Stroop specifically, several versions of the Stroop task are available for Inquisit [here](http://www.millisecond.com/download/library/stroop/).

Randall Engle's lab also maintains a set of validated [working memory tasks](http://englelab.gatech.edu/tasks.html), which are available on request to researchers. They include full and shortened versions of operation-, symmetry-, reading- and rotation-span for E-Prime 2.0.

Assuming I read the question correctly, any of these should satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Would I be able to easily run Inquisit side-by-side with the primary task, just to trigger the secondary tasks? I would prefer having control over how to show the tasks for minimal intrusion into the actual work environment of the user. Same question for E-prime.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Hard to say without knowing your setup. Inquisit has a 30-day trial version you can download, though, so I suppose you could quickly find out.

Comment: If not I can still just export the particular tasks I suppose, possibly manually (if that would be allowed).